# In multiple files upload(PHP/Mysql), the images are stored in single column. Want to store each image in single row with same id

Tags: php, mysql

[image: table1]

right now the images are stored in single column. I want to store each image in single row.

> eg. the id "1149" has two images, now i want the image 1136524631.png in next row with same id i.e 1149. Similar for the id "1150".

here is the code->

```
if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'name' ] ) ) {
    // Count # of uploaded files in array
    $total = count( $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'name' ] );

    $image_name = array();
// Loop through each file
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $total; $i++ ) {
        //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'tmp_name' ][ $i ];
        $i_names = $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'name' ][ $i ];
        $i_sizes = $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'size' ][ $i ];
        $i_errors = $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'error' ][ $i ];
        $i_tmp_names = $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'tmp_name' ][ $i ];
        $i_types = $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'type' ][ $i ];
        $exts = pathinfo( $i_names, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        $msgs = '';

        if ( $i_errors == 0 ) {
            if ( $exts == 'jpg' || $exts == 'jpeg' || $exts == 'png' || $exts == 'gif' ) {
                if ( $i_sizes > 0 ) {
                    $image_name[$i] = rand() . '.' . $exts;
                    $paths = '../img' . $image_name[$i];
                    $uploads = copy( $i_tmp_names, $paths );
                    if ( $uploads ) {
                        $image_name[$i] = $image_name[$i];
                    } else {
                        $image_name[$i] = '';
                    }
                } else {
                    $image_name[$i] = '';
                }
            } else {
                $image_name[$i] = '';
            }
        } else {
            $image_name[$i] = '';
        }
    }
} 



$image_name = implode(", ", $image_name);

mysql_query( "insert into posts(user_id,title,email,description,`condition`,contact_info,looking_for,price,location,image,is_active,created) values('$user_id','$title','$email','$description','$condition','$contact_info','$looking_for','$price','$location','$image_name','1','$created_date')" );
```

Comment: Post your code how you are saving it? we will check and let you know the solution

Comment: So same with the user_id?

Comment: store this in a separate table

Comment: @Strawberry , yes i created a seperate table for this. but how to store these values in each row as i want..

Comment: @Mukiikumar you can't do that if `id` column is primary. Is there any particular reason why would you want to store it like that? You can simply `json_encode` the array with images and save them in one column, and when you retrieve it just do `json_decode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:**
 I solved the query. Please see the below code snippet

```
if ( $uploads ) {
                 //insert data into the database
                 $image_id = mysql_query( "insert into post_images(post_id,name) value('$postID','$image_name')" );
                        } else {
                            $image_name = '';
                        }
```

What i did? I just insert and save the image value in another table with "Foreign Key" and change the name

```
$image_id = array();
```

instead of `$image_name = array();`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for why you want them in the same row?

You cannot have a row inside a row, so you will have to concatenate the images if you want them in the same row (and later you will be angry at yourself for doing it). The good way to do this is to have another table for images with foreign key to this table and join them when selecting the data

Comment: yeah i create another table with foreign key and that table also storing the images but in same way as i mentioned above

Comment: In that second table you could have another primary id so you can have several images for the same foreign key

Comment: yeah there is primary key also. @rypskar. i searched every tut but didn't find the solution for this

Comment: Then you should try to have them as different rows and use a join when selecting them, appending new images to old will be a pain to maintain